How to Create a SQL VIEW to Indicate User's Favorite Recipes in a Result Set?
I need help writing a SQL VIEW query for the following scenario:
Here is the query which I have tried but it only return the matched data, because any someone user_id is matched to any of the recipe:
CREATE VIEW view_recipebank AS
SELECT
r.*,
IFNULL(f.status, "0") as favourite,
f.user_id as f_user_id,
f.status as f_status,
FROM tbl_recipes as r
LEFT JOIN tbl_favourites as f ON f.type = "recipe" AND f.type_id = r.recipe_id
WHERE
r.status = '1' AND r.is_hide_recipebank = '0'

I have two tables, tbl_recipes and tbl_favourites. The tbl_recipes table stores all the recipes and is used to display recipes to users with pagination. The tbl_favourites table stores the recipe_id and user_id to track which recipes each user has marked as their favorites.
I need a VIEW query that returns all recipes along with an additional column that indicates whether each recipe is a favorite for a specific user. If a recipe is a favorite, the column should return 1; otherwise, it should return 0.
How can I write a VIEW query to achieve this? Thank you!

When you want info about every user and every recipe you first cross join users and recipes and than collect what you want from other tables (favorites).

Personally, I would not use a view for this, but if you want to use a view, as Serg suggested in the comments, you should first CROSS JOIN with tbl_users:
CREATE VIEW view_recipebank AS
SELECT
    r.*,
    IFNULL(f.status, 0) as favourite,
    u.user_id as user_id
FROM tbl_recipes as r
CROSS JOIN tbl_users as u
LEFT JOIN tbl_favourites as f
    ON f.type = 'recipe'
    AND f.type_id = r.recipe_id
    AND f.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE r.status = 1
AND r.is_hide_recipebank = 0;

SELECT * FROM view_recipebank WHERE user_id = 2;

Here's a db<>fiddle.
With your first attempt at the view, when it is queried with f_user_id in the WHERE clause, the LEFT JOIN is implicitly changed to an INNER JOIN, as it is referring to the table on the right-hand side of the LEFT JOIN. By adding the CROSS JOIN to tbl_users, when you have user_id in the WHERE clause you are specifying the user_id to be used in the LEFT JOIN, which then functions as you intend.
Assuming the view is always queried with a user_id, the additional CROSS JOIN is very light-weight as it is just a simple PK lookup.
